# Visual Studio 2013 will not show design view

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm having a problem with Visual Studio 2013, the latest build off MSDN.

When in an ASP.Net application I cannot see the design view.  When I switch to design view all I see is the message `Loading Master Page...` in the upper left hand corner.

Anyone else see this issue or have a work around?

Comment: can you pls put your code here..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have added some controls which has come constructor logic failing due to some dependency that is causing your form not to open in design mode.

Try move your control from Form designer & add the control in code editor in Form Load event .

Also try to debug your code.

Comment: what do you mean by "constructor logic failing due to some dependency", kindly elaborate a bit, I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem, it actually does display in designer but takes a  lot more time like mine took approx 10 minutes. In my case I'm using 2 ListViews and a nested listviews with their datasources and nested master pages. So I think it makes sense to take time in loading the designer.

Answer (score -2):

At the solution explorer, right click on the file and select open with then select -Web Forms Editor- you can set it as default if you want. To see the code, right click on the file and select -View Mark Up - I hope it helps.